# timeout or close when process is finished

Tags: windows, batch-file, timeout, batch-processing, kill

I have a `X.exe` program that takes about 2-6 hours to finish. Exact time is unknown, but I'd like to implement a threshold of 6.5 or 7 hours. If this program does not return any value by this amount of time, it will be killed. How do I implement this using batch `*.bat` files?

Here is what I had so far: a timer `bat1.bat` and an actual `bat2.bat`.

bat1.bat:

```
start cmd /C bat2.bat & timeout /t 25200 & taskkill /im X.exe /f
```

bat2.bat:

```
cd blah
bat1.bat
```

The problem with this approach is that only after 25200 seconds (or 7 hours) the timer will be stopped, and it won't be terminated before that limit. How do I tell the computer that if the program `X.exe` is finished then don't wait anymore?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you set it up x.exe to run as a scheduled task you could tell it to stop the task after 8 hours. Unfortunately your only options in task scheduler is 1, 2, 4, 8 or 12 hours.  What you could do though is use the `TASKLIST` command to check if the program is running every 300 seconds.  If it is not running then the bat file can exit.  If it is still running check how many seconds it is has run so far and kill it if it is 25,200 seconds.

Comment: @Squashman thank you for the idea and command. I have a simple script `tasklist /fi "imagename eq X.exe"`, but how do you return the amount of time which `X.exe` has been running? can you provide a formal answer so that I can accept it also? thanks!!!

Comment: Set three variables.  %checktime% %elapsedtime% and %killtime%.  Use the %checktime% variable with the `TIMEOUT` command.  Then use the `TASKLIST` command to see if the process is running.  If it is running add %checktime% to %elapsedtime%.  Then check if %elapsedtime% is greater than or equal to %killtime%.  If the kill time condition has not been met use the `GOTO` command to loop back to a label before the `TIMEOUT` command. If the kill time condition has been met then use the `TASKKILL` command to stop the process.

Comment: @Squashman thanks alot, i think i figured it out according to your above comment. have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Squashman i was able to build a script on my own. seem to work fine

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "checktime=60"
set /a "elapsedtime=0"
set /a "killtime=150"
set XProg=X.exe
start cmd /C runTest.bat 
timeout /t 10
:while1
    echo Go to WHILE loop.
    echo elapsedtime = %elapsedtime% 
    echo killtime = %killtime%
    set /a "timeleft = %killtime% - %elapsedtime%"
    echo timeleft = %timeleft%
    if /i %timeleft% geq 0 (
        tasklist /fi "imagename eq %XProg%" 2>NUL | find /i /n "%XProg%">NUL
        if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
            echo %XProg% is still running...
        ) else (
            echo %XProg% is finished before timer.
        )
        set /a "elapsedtime = elapsedtime + checktime"
        timeout /t %checktime%
        goto :while1
    ) else (
        taskkill /im %XProg% /f
        echo %XProg% is terminated.
    )
```

lessons learned:
1. hard to compare numeric variables in batch (compare diff with 0 instead)
2. terminated first time `elaspedtime > killtime` (might be a bit longer than `killtime` depending how often it checks)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a much simpler solution:

```
rem Start the process that will kill the X.exe program after 7 hours
start "WaitingToKill" cmd /C timeout /t 25200 ^& taskkill /im X.exe /f

rem Run the X.exe program and wait for it to terminate
X.exe

rem Kill the killer process and terminate
taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq WaitingToKill" /f
```

In this method there is not any additional code running at same time; just the waiting state of `timeout` command.

**EDIT**: *Some explanations added*

Note that both the "WaitingToKill" cmd.exe process with the `timeout` command and the `X.exe` program are running in parallel. If the `timeout` command ends after 7 hours, the `taskkill /im X.exe /f` command is executed, the `X.exe` program is killed and both cmd.exe processes ends.

If the `X.exe` program ends before the 7 hours, the Batch file execute the next line *as usual*. This line is `taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq WaitingToKill" /f`, so the window with the `timeout` command is killed and both cmd.exe processes ends.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that's why exactly the question is posed: `X.exe` sometimes finishes before the timer, hence i'd like to check periodically if the program is still running. the answer that you propose are almost identical with my former solution. am i mistaking somewhere?

Comment: You don't need to periodically check anything: both processes must end when the other process ends, so it is only necessary to wait that one process ends and kill the other process at that time. See my edit...

Comment: To be clearer: When kill `X.exe` program? when `timeout` command ends. When kill `timeout` command? when `X.exe` program ends (unless I misunderstood your requirement **`:/`**)...

Comment: So? Did this much simpler solution worked correctly?

Comment: +1. Nice idea! However `taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq WaitingToKill" /f` will not kill `timeout.exe` because it has no `Window Title`. May I suggest you to replace it by `taskkill /im cmd.exe /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq WaitingToKill" /f /t`. Also I have an idea to extend your solution, to not have a separate window for the *Killer* process which I can post as an alternate answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried various solutions but in the end this is really cumbersome in batch.
If you are willing to use an external tool the simplest way is

`"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\timeout.exe" 5 .\test.exe`

It properly returns the exit code of the test process, also works if you spawn multiple test processes simultaneously and does not pop up windows all the time.